# solving a recurrence: T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n(logn)^2

Tags: recursion

I'm trying to solve this recursive function but i reached a dead end:

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n(logn)^2
```

I tried the master rule (with the 3 cases) and non of the cases applied. I also tried iteration method and got a complex equation...
Can anybody give me a final solution or a method how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly have you tried

Comment: i compared n(logn)^2 to n^log4=n^2 and found that non of the 3 cases of the master method applies.

plus, in the iteration method i got to a formula like this:
256T(n/16) + 3/4n(logn)^2 + 3n(logn)^2 - 7/2n

Comment: I get `T(n) = n^2*T(1) + n*((6*n-2)*(log 2)^2 - 4*(log 2)*(log n) - (log n)^2)` (where `x^2` is the square of `x`, not a bitwise xor).  I had some help from Wolfram Alpha.